# How do I set a Collection View Item as delegate?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a song playing app.  The songs are loaded into a NSCollectionView.  There are two controllers:

- WindowController
- SongViewController (the controller for the CollectionViewItem's view)

Both the window and each individual song view have a play button.  So when I press play from the window the song view's play button needs to update to show the pause/play status, and vice versa.

When I press play in the SongView, no problem, I can set the `_delegate = [[NSApp mainWindow] windowController]`

But here's my problem: what about the other way around?  How do I set the SongViewController as the delegate from the WindowController.  There are about 20 CollectionViewItems and thus 20 SongViewControllers.  How do I find and set the right one.

Also, I'm pretty new to Objective-C, if I'm approaching this in a weird way please tell.

:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSCollectionView has a method `(NSCollectionViewItem *)itemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index` to access the NSCollectionViewItem at a specific index.  NSCollectionViewItem inherits from NSViewController, so you can access the view it controls to set delegates.

Though that is the technical answer, I've tackled the problem using Notification Center and binding, which i find much simpler and more efficient.